# itemtap is not getting fired in list

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

i have loaded `json` data into `list` in sencha touch using `itemTpl` , everything is getting displayed properly as of now but somehow `itemtap` event of the list is not getting fired.
 i don't know what is the reason, following is my code where one can see the `listeners` inside `config` and nothing happens there.

```
Ext.define('demo.view.ProfileList',{
    extend:'Ext.dataview.List',
    xtype:'profilelist',
    requires:[
        'demo.store.ProfileStore',
        'Ext.plugin.ListPaging'
    ],
    config:{
        plugins: [{
            xclass: 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
            autoPaging: true
        }],
        store:'ProfileStore',
        itemTpl: [ 
            '<div class="demo-inner-list-item">',
                '<table border="0" >',
                    '<tr>',
                        '<td rowspan="5">',
                            '<div class="demo-img-frame">',
                            '</div>',
                        '</td>',
                        '<td class="demo-list-text">{member_name}</td>',
                    '</tr>',
                    '<tr>',
                        '<td class="demo-list-sub-text">{member_status}</td>',
                    '</tr>',
                    '<tr>',
                        '<td class="demo-list-sub-text">{member_dob:date("F j , Y")}</td>',
                    '</tr>',
                    '<tr>',
                        '<td class="demo-list-sub-text">{member_designation} - {member_work_loc}</td>',
                    '</tr>',
                '</table>',
            '</div>'
        ],
        listeners: {
            itemtap: function (list, index, item, evt) {
                console.log("TAP");
            }
        }
    },
    initialize: function() {
        Ext.getStore('ProfileStore').load();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the problem i haven't called `this.callParent()` in my `initialize`function of `List`